# Firebase Add Child Data without Overwrite in Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've searched through many answers about how to solve this issue but I still cant seem to understand how to get my data structured the way I want in Firebase. Per the Firebase documentation on structuring your data, I am trying to add an index of IDs to a node under my user with a value of true set to them. This is the code I've come up with, but it just keeps overwriting the previous ID that is under the users "`open_bounties`" node. Each time I add an issue to the database, I want the issue ID to be added to the users "`open_bounties`" node so that it is easy to index the users open bounties.

[Firebase flatten data structures docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data?authuser=0)

Here is the code I have for pushing an issue to the database.

```
    database.ref('issues/' + issueHashId).set({
      user_opened: userOpened,
      issue_url: getFullIssueUrlFromId(issueUrlId),
      bounty_amount_posted: bountyAmount,
      is_open: true
    })

    database.ref('open_issues/' + issueHashId).set({
      user_opened: userOpened,
      issue_url: getFullIssueUrlFromId(issueUrlId),
      bounty_amount_posted: bountyAmount
    })

    //This is the part in question
    var userOpenBountiesRef = database.ref('users/' + userOpened).child("open_bounties")
    userOpenBountiesRef.set({
      [issueHashId]: true
    })
```

Here is what the structure looks like. As you can see, the only value in the users open bounties is the most recent record ID entered.

Data Structure

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var userOpenBountiesRef = database.ref('users/' + userOpened).child("open_bounties");
userOpenBountiesRef.child(issueHashId).set(true)
```

Comment: Your updated suggestion will end up creating a status record set to true, which I understand can work, but its data I dont need. Per the documentation, I am trying to make just a list of open bounty IDs that are set to true under the `open_bounties` reference.

Comment: Doesnt work. True is not valid there, its a syntax error.

Comment: hmm that should be a key value pair.

Comment: Is there no way to append something without push? Push lokos to do what I want, but I dont want the auto generated key.

Comment: I edited your answer with the one that worked. Waiting on review. Your answer got me where I needed to be to figure it out.

Comment: ohh man i forgot about the curly brackets. true is a Boolean value :P.